# Checking if two FeatureCollections are equivalent

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm writing a method to get the GAUL geometries simply by names and content_level in Python ([pygaul](https://github.com/12rambau/pygaul)). In my test suit, I want to make sure that one of my method is not case-sensitive and thus generate twice the same `ee.FeatureCollection`:

```py
fc1 = pygaul.get_items(name="Singapore")
fc2 = pygaul.get_items(name="singaPORE")
```

The only way I know to check if the 2 are the same is to perform a comparison client side:

```py
assert fc1.getInfo() == fc2.getInfo()
```

Is there a better way to do the same server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, to implement a server-side, generic, deep equality check between two feature collections would be pretty involved and expensive.

- Both should have same properties
- Both should have same number of features
- You probably should join them on `system:index`, then start comparing each feature:

  - Same properties
  - Same geometry

In your case, since you know what you're just filtering a collection, you could get away with just checking that they contain the same features:

```
ids1 = fc1.aggregate_array('system:index').sort()
ids2 = fc2.aggregate_array('system:index').sort()
assert ids1.equals(ids2).getInfo()
```

That would transfer a lot less data to the client.